# How to add Swipe Down Refresh feature in a Tab View Layout

Tags: android

This is the MainActivity of my Tab View Layout

```
package com.nitol.aust.cse.austclassmanager;


public class ResultCheckActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

private TabLayout t1;
private ViewPager vp1;
Toolbar toolbar;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
NavigationView navigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.navi_draw_result);

    t1 = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab1);
    vp1 = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.ViewPager1);


    setUpMyViewPager(vp1);
    t1.setupWithViewPager(vp1);


    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout) ;
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle
            (this,drawerLayout,toolbar, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(5).setChecked(true);



}

void setUpMyViewPager(ViewPager vp){

    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPagerAdapter.addMyFragment(new WebViewEvents(),"News & Events");
    viewPagerAdapter.addMyFragment(new WebViewAcademic(),"Academic Calendar");
    viewPagerAdapter.addMyFragment(new WebViewTheory(),"Theory Results");
    viewPagerAdapter.addMyFragment(new WebViewLab(),"Lab Results");
    viewPagerAdapter.addMyFragment(new WebViewTeacher(),"Faculty Members");


    vp.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
}



class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> my_list = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    private final List<String> my_title = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return my_list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return my_list.size();
    }


    void addMyFragment(Fragment f, String title){
        my_list.add(f);
        my_title.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return my_title.get(position);
    }

}




@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }

    else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id){

        case R.id.home:
            Intent intent0 = new Intent(ResultCheckActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent0);
            finish();

            break;

        case R.id.routine:
            Intent intent = new Intent(ResultCheckActivity.this, ClassRoutineActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

            break;

        case R.id.cgpa:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(ResultCheckActivity.this, CgpaCalculator.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            finish();

            break;

        case R.id.details:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Class Details",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;

        case R.id.quiz:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Quiz Reminder",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;

        case R.id.result:

            break;


        case R.id.profile:
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(ResultCheckActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
            finish();

            break;

        case R.id.about:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"About",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;

        case R.id.settings:
            Intent intent4 = new Intent(ResultCheckActivity.this, Settings.class);
            startActivity(intent4);
            finish();

            break;

    }

    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);


    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tool,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == R.id.tool_settings){
        Intent intent = new Intent(ResultCheckActivity.this, Settings.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
    else if(id == R.id.tool_about){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This is About !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

And this is my those tabs where i want to add refresh feature

```
void setUpMyViewPager(ViewPager vp){

ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new 
ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPagerAdapter.addMyFragment(new WebViewEvents(),"News & Events");
viewPagerAdapter.addMyFragment(new WebViewAcademic(),"Academic Calendar");
viewPagerAdapter.addMyFragment(new WebViewTheory(),"Theory Results");
viewPagerAdapter.addMyFragment(new WebViewLab(),"Lab Results");
viewPagerAdapter.addMyFragment(new WebViewTeacher(),"Faculty Members");


vp.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
}
```

Now suppose i want to add refresh on "WebViewEvents" class. The class is given below

```
package com.nitol.aust.cse.austclassmanager;

public class WebViewEvents  extends Fragment {

View v;
WebView wb4;

private String currentUrl = "http://aust.edu/news_events.htm";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview_event, container,false);

    wb4 = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView_event);

    wb4.setInitialScale(1);
    wb4.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wb4.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wb4.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wb4.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    wb4.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    wb4.loadUrl(currentUrl);
    wb4.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    wb4.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wb4.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wb4.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wb4.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);


    return v;

}

}
```

I found some instructions here but maximum of those was said that i have to @Override onRefresh() method...but i declared my class as a non activity class. so in a non activity class , i can not override a method. that's why i am not finding my solutions...

Answer (score 1):

You just need to read [docs on SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/index.html)

First, add SwipeRefreshLayout to your activity layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    // here is your content

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Then find instance of swipe refresh layout in your activity:

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
```

And set refresh listener in which trigger your update method

```
/*
 * Sets up a SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener that is invoked when the user
 * performs a swipe-to-refresh gesture.
 */
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
    new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onRefresh called from SwipeRefreshLayout");

            // This method performs the actual data-refresh operation.
            // The method calls setRefreshing(false) when it's finished.
            myUpdateOperation();
        }
    }
);
```

For more information read docs, link in the beginning of the answer.

Also you might look at google samples:

- [SwipeRefreshLayoutBasic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-SwipeRefreshLayoutBasic/#readme)
- [SwipeRefreshListFragment](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-SwipeRefreshListFragment/#readme)

List of all google samples you can find [here](https://developer.android.com/samples/index.html)

Hope it helps

Comment: i want to add this in a non activity class. so in a non activity class, it is not possible to override a method. thats why i am facing problem

Comment: @NitolDasNeel you want to add swipe-refresh to your `public class WebViewEvents  extends Fragment`? If yes, then just replace 'activity' with 'fragment' in my answer (add SwipeRefreshLayout to fragment layout, find it and provide onRefreshListener). Note, you say that it is not possible to override onRefresh method in a non activity class, but Activity doesn't have onRefresh method as well, so you can't override such method. What you can do is implement listener by your activity/fragment like: `public class WebViewEvents  extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener`

Comment: Then you'd be able to (how you call it) override onRefresh method (but actually is implement and not override)

Comment: may be you are not clear about my problem. Ok , i have fixed my problem. i posted my corrected code below

Answer (score 0):

**Finally this is worked for me**

```
package com.nitol.aust.cse.austclassmanager;
public class WebViewEvents  extends Fragment{

View v;
WebView wb4;
SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;

private String currentUrl = "http://aust.edu/news_events.htm";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview_event, container,false);

    mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
    wb4 = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView_event);

    wb4.setInitialScale(1);
    wb4.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wb4.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wb4.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wb4.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    wb4.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    wb4.loadUrl(currentUrl);
    wb4.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    wb4.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wb4.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wb4.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wb4.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    wb4.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
            new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    wb4.loadUrl(currentUrl);
                }
            }
    );


    return v;

}

public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        currentUrl = url;
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}
```

}

**I added this override method inside my class**

```
mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
        new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                wb4.loadUrl(currentUrl);
            }
        }
);
```

**Then added this to stop the refreshing animation**

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    currentUrl = url;
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
}
```

}
**Don't forget to add the instance of the last stopping animation impliment**

```
wb4.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```